# I cant save my users when I use bcrypt with mongoose pre

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

The problem start when I use the bcrypt middleware to encrypt my password.
Whitout bcrypt I could save the users, but with it not now.

My users.js file

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    displayName: String,
    password: { type: String, select: false }
})

UserSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
    let user = this
    if (!user.isModified('password')) {
        return next();
    }

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) return next(err)

        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) return next(err)

            user.password = hash
            next();
        })
    })
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

My router.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = require('./model/user')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')


router.post('/user', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    let user = new User()
    user.email = req.body.email
    user.displayName = req.body.displayName
    user.password = req.body.password

    user.save((err, stored) => {
        res.status(200).send({
            user: stored
        })
    })
})
```

This is the server response:

```
{}
```

My db is not affected...

Answer (score 1):

I can see two mistakes in the provided code:

**1. `this` in the pre-save middleware is not a user document instance**

Arrow functions do not provide their own `this` binding:

> In arrow functions, this retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's this. [[source]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Change your code to the following:

```js
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    const user = this;
    // ... code omitted
});
```

**2. Not handling duplicate key MongoError**

The request might fail with `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection` since `email` field is unique. You are ignoring such fail and since `stored` in your `user.save()` is `undefined` the response from the server is going to be an empty object.

To fix this issue you need to add a handler in the following code:

```js
user.save((err, stored) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err; // some handling
  }
  res.status(200).send({user: stored});
});
```